# How do you load MPV Lua scripts with the C Plugin?

Tags: c++, lua, mpv

After realizing it is nearly impossible to find help on getting keybindings to work with the C plugin in MPV ([Possible to allow key bindings with MPV C API when no video (GUI) is being shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67011056/possible-to-allow-key-bindings-with-mpv-c-api-when-no-video-gui-is-being-shown)), I decided to learn some Lua to help with the cause. Problem is, the docs aren't very clear on how to add **Lua scripts** with the **C plugin**, what I could find out was that `check_error(mpv_set_option_string(ctx, "load-scripts", "yes"));` should be called before initializing mpv in the C plugin, which points out that there should be a way to add scripts... When loading a script in the terminal you can do `mpv video.mp4 --scripts="script_name.lua"` and that will call the script from inside **$HOME/.config/mpv**... How do I achieve the calling of Lua scripts in the C plugin for MPV? I tried a few things including `check_error(mpv_set_option_string(ctx, "scripts", "test.lua"));` and `check_error(mpv_set_property_string(ctx, "scripts", "test.lua"));` and `const char *cmd2[] = {"scripts", "test.lua", NULL}; check_error(mpv_command(ctx, cmd2));`, none of which worked...

How do I call a Lua script for MPV from the C Plugin?

Below is the code I'm using to test things out:

```
// Build with: g++ main.cpp -o output `pkg-config --libs --cflags mpv`

#include <iostream>
#include <mpv/client.h>

static inline void check_error(int status)
{
    if (status < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "mpv API error: " << mpv_error_string(status) << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "pass a single media file as argument" << std::endl;

        return 1;
    }

    mpv_handle *ctx = mpv_create();
    if (!ctx)
    {
        std::cout << "failed creating context" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Enable default key bindings, so the user can actually interact with
    // the player (and e.g. close the window).
    check_error(mpv_set_option_string(ctx, "input-default-bindings", "yes"));
    mpv_set_option_string(ctx, "input-vo-keyboard", "yes");
    check_error(mpv_set_option_string(ctx, "load-scripts", "yes"));
    check_error(mpv_set_option_string(ctx, "scripts", "test.lua")); // DOES NOT WORK :(
    int val = 1;
    check_error(mpv_set_option(ctx, "osc", MPV_FORMAT_FLAG, &val));

    // Done setting up options.
    check_error(mpv_initialize(ctx));

    // Play the file passed in as a parameter when executing program.
    const char *cmd[] = {"loadfile", argv[1], NULL};
    check_error(mpv_command(ctx, cmd));

    // check_error(mpv_set_option_string(ctx, "scripts", "test.lua"));
    check_error(mpv_set_option_string(ctx, "shuffle", "yes")); // shuffle videos
    check_error(mpv_set_option_string(ctx, "loop-playlist", "yes")); // loop playlists
    // check_error(mpv_set_option_string(ctx, "aspect", "0:0")); // set aspect
    
    // Let it play, and wait until the user quits.
    while (1)
    {
        mpv_event *event = mpv_wait_event(ctx, 10000);
        std::cout << "event: " << mpv_event_name(event->event_id) << std::endl;

        if (event->event_id == MPV_EVENT_SHUTDOWN)
            break;
    }

    mpv_terminate_destroy(ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does using the command `"load_script"` instead of `"scripts"` work?

Comment: No, unfortunately not :/
It says 'mpv API error: option not found'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing around more with the `mpv_set_property_string` command, I discovered that you have to specify the **FULL** path to the Lua file, it by defaults searches for the file in the directory it is being played in, so if I tried to play it in /home/ it will search for /home/test.lua, so to get it to work I had to do `check_error(mpv_set_property_string(ctx, "scripts", "/home/netsu/.config/mpv/test.lua"));` (give the absolute path)